# Oracle : Selecting date by month with where clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I came across a problem that in selecting the date for current desired month and year. I tried the 2 statements shown below but failed to execute the query

```
select to_char(sysdate, 'Month') from income

select * from income where to_char(sysdate,month) = 'feb'
```

**Update**

But after researching and learning more in depth on oracle docs website. What i came out with is to use  "between" clause. Specifying the first day and last day of the month . Doing so, it will execute the desired month/year

For an example

```
SELECT column_name
FROM table_name where column_name = (Your own value) AND
column_date >= to_date('01/02/2012', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
and column_date <  to_date('01/03/2012', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
```

I hope this help :)

Comment: Do you want to select data for February of any year or do you want data for February of the current year? (Or something else?)

Comment: Also, does your table have a column with a `DATE`  or `TIMESTAMP` data type?

Comment: Your where-condition uses sysdate instead of one of the table columns. This means you get either all rows or none. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you after something like:

```
select *
from   income
where  <date_column> >= to_date('01/05/2019', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
and    <date_column> <  to_date('01/06/2019', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
```

(replacing `<date_column>` with the name of the date column in your income table that you want to filter on)?

Comment: I'ld prefer `BETWEEN`. Of course, with upper limit equal to 31/05.

Comment: @RobertKock That would not get rows with dates between `2019-05-31 00:00:01` and `2019-05-31 23:59:59`.

Comment: @MT0: you're right in case the date column reports the time as well. Forget my comment.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the following query:

```
select *
from   income
where  to_char(<date_column>,'MON-RRRR') = 'MAY-2019';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass in a string like `'May 2012'`, then I would recommend:

```
select i.*
from income i
where i.datecol >= to_date('May 2012', 'Mon YYYY') and
      i.datecol < to_date('May 2012', 'Mon YYYY') + interval '1' month;
```

That said, I think your application should turn the string value into a date range and you should use that range in your query:

```
select i.*
from income i
where i.datecol >= :datestart
      i.datecol < :dateend + interval '1 day';
```

I strong encourage you to avoid `between` with dates, particularly in Oracle.  The `date` data type has a built-in time component, and that can throw off the comparisons.